# postgresql copy from one table to another when the table updates

Tags: postgresql

What I would like is when one row of a table is updated and a new table that will duplicate the original table will update as well but the problem is the original table is a master table that depends on other tables. Any idea how to do this? I'm very new to postgresql.

Answer (score 1):

This is what triggers are for, assuming that the source and destination tables are in the same DB. In this case I think you need an `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE` trigger.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: Becuase the original table is a inherited table where it will inherit data from the child tables. So there will be no rows in that table itself so no insert or update or delete clause in it so I cant really do a trigger function

Comment: You must add triggers on each child table. There isn't really a way around that.